# A good maggid shiur who goes through an entire sefer of hashkafa

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, product-recommendation, mussar-ethics, middos-character-traits, recording

I have gone through the Mesilas Yesharim superficially once, I am now learning Likutei Amarim (Tanya) and The Kuzari. I have listened to shiurim on Chovos Halevavos, and Alei Shur. I have dipped my toes in Rambam's Yesodei Hatorah and I have just found good shiruim on mishlei (at least the first 5 perakim). I am looking for things to enhance emunah and my ability to tackle middos. To do that, I really desire a good maggid shiur who is online that I can listen to.

Does anyone know a good maggid shiur online who goes through an entire sefer of hashkafa?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeta Shmuel!

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your title to match the question. You can rollback the edit, or further edit yourself, using the [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/81351/edit) function.

Comment: Rabbi Triebitz  has a [series](http://www.hashkafacircle.com/category/ikarim/) on the 13 principles of Rambam. Many of the are fairly difficult, often delving into much of the philosophical background. He also has [a 10 part series](http://www.hashkafacircle.com/category/emergence-of-ethical-man/) on Emergence of Ethical man. Many of his other lectures on http://www.hashkafacircle.com/ may be of interest to you.

Comment: Since you mentioned one of Ramchal's works, you may want to listen to online shiurim by Rav Mendel Kessin who is an unbelieveable Maggid shiur with specialty in Derech Hashem and Chafetz Chaim's Lashin Hara series. I don't have the URL, now, but if you type his name in Google, etc. you should find it. I know Rabbi Kessin personally, very well.

Comment: I would recommend getting a chavrusa instead of doing it online - that's how mussar is generally learnt. Its much better than online because you get to read, think about how what you are reading applies to you, and discuss it with your chavrusa. Its much more personalized. Also, the Rav Avigdor Miller mesilas yesharim is amazing.

Answer (score 3):

Because [YUTorah.org](http://www.yutorah.org/) has so much, I am sure such a thing must exist there.  In a brief search, I found Rav Moshe Weinberger has a series of 155(!) shiurim on 'The Bilvavi on Mesilat Yesharim' (First in the series [here](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/825457/rabbi-moshe-weinberger/the-bilvavi-on-mesilas-yesharim-1-there-are-no-shortcuts-to-better-midos/)).

Rabbi Yakov Haber is currently going through Nefesh HaChaim and has recently uploaded [shiur 101](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/884956/rabbi-yaacov-haber/nefesh-hachaim-101-accessing-the-neshama-rabbi-yaacov-haber/) from this series.

Rabbi Haber in the past taught Tomer Devorah, which begins [here](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/788132/rabbi-yaacov-haber/tomer-devora-intro-1/).

Since you mention you are now learning Tanya, Rabbi Zev Reichman taught shiurim on it, though not on all of it.  You can begin them [here](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/746175/rabbi-zev-reichman/tanya-1-perek-alef-introduction-and-the-prenatal-oath/).  Rabbi Bentzion Twerski has taught all or almost all of it, and can be found [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/author/rabbi-benzion-twerski/#?) (not YUTorah).  And of course [chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/tanya.asp?tdate=9/26/2017) has shiurim on Tanya every single day.

Obviously there are many others.  I would encourage one to search for one's desired sefer and perhaps someone will have taught it.